# Writing to error channel halts the execution

Tags: go

I am trying to launch multiple go-routines using `sync.WorkGroup` and collect errors from those workers using channels. (Is this a good approach?). The program seems to halt whenever I try writing to the error channel. Can't figure out the reason for it.

The scenario would look something like this -

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func worker(id int, i int, errs chan<- errs) {
   defer wg.Done()
   errs <- fmt.Errorf("Sample Error") // This is where the executions seems to be stuck
   return 
}

func main() {
    errs := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
 
    for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(w, w, errs)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("Hello, all tasks done.") // Never executed.
    close(errs)
    for err := range errs{
         fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
   }

}
```

Comment: You're waiting for the goroutines to return before you attempt to read from the `errs` channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A channel write will block if there is no other goroutine reading from it. When you write to the error channel, there are no other goroutines reading from it so it'll block.

There are several problems with your program:

- You have to start reading from the error channel before calling `wg.Wait`, because that will wait for the goroutines to complete, but goroutines will not run if you're not reading from the error channel.
- You are trying to read from the errors channel after you close it.

Something like this should work:

```
errs := make(chan int, numJobs)
go func() {
    for err := range errs{
       fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
 }()
for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(w, w, results)
}
```